# Contour method to solve $\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Prove the following using complex analysis

$$\tag{1}\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)$$

I found this problem in Schaum's outlines of complex variables.

I thought that we could solve the problem using a similar method to evaluating

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

Where we integrate the function

$$f=\frac{\log(1-iz)}{z^2+1}$$

around half a circle in the upper half plane and chosing an analytic branch of the logarithm in the region.

I spent so much time on (1) without success.

Comment: Your statement cannot be proven since it is incorrect. The true statement is
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx = C + \dfrac{\pi \ln(2)}4$$where $C$ is the Catalan's constant.

Comment: @user141421, I am really disappointed. I should have checked the solution before trying the problem. I never thought that the textbook will have a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
     ={\rm G} + {1 \over 4}\,\pi\,\ln\pars{2}\quad\mbox{where}\quad
     {\rm G} \equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}
     = 0.9159\ldots}$ is the [Catalan Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_constant).

> Let's consider the integral
>   $$
> {\cal I} \equiv \int_{\rm C}{\ln^{2}\pars{z} \over z^{2} + 2z + 2}\,\dd z
> \quad\mbox{where}\quad
> \left\vert%
> \begin{array}{l}
> {\rm C}\ \mbox{is a 'key-hole' contour which takes care of the}\
> \\
> {\large \ln}-\mbox{branch cut}.
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
>   Zeros of $\ds{z^{2} + 2z + 2=0}$ are given by 
>   $\ds{z_{\pm} = -1 \pm \ic = \root{2}\expo{\pm 3\ic\pi/4}}$.

\begin{align}
{\cal I}&=2\pi\ic\,\bracks{{\ln^{2}\pars{z_{+}} \over z_{+} - z_{-}}
+ {\ln^{2}\pars{z_{-}} \over z_{-} - z_{+}}}
=2\pi\ic\,{%
\bracks{\ln\pars{2}/2 + 3\ic\pi/4}^{2}
-\bracks{\ln\pars{2}/2 - 3\ic\pi/4}^{2}\over 2\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\pi\bracks{\ic\,{3\pi \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}}
={3 \over 2}\,\pi^{2}\ln\pars{2}\,\ic\tag{1}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{0}{\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{-x} + \ic\pi} \over x^{2} + 2x + 2}\,\dd x
> +
> \int_{0}^{-\infty}{\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{-x} - \ic\pi} \over x^{2} + 2x + 2}\,\dd x
> =-4\pi\ic\int_{0}^{-\infty}{\ln\pars{-x} \over x^{2} + 2x + 2}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=4\pi\ic\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x
> =4\pi\ic\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x
> +
> 4\pi\ic\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=4\pi\ic\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x
> +
> 4\pi\ic\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
={{\cal I} \over 4\pi\ic} - \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x
={3 \over 8}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
-\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x}\tag{2}
$$
where we used result $\pars{1}$.

> $\ds{z_{\pm} = 1 \pm \ic}$ are the zeros of
>   $\ds{z^{2} - 2z + 2 = 0}$.
>   $\ds{\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x}}$ is evaluated as follows:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\dd x}=
> \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\pars{{1 \over x - z_{+}} - {1 \over x - z_{-}}}
> \,{1 \over z_{+} - z_{-}}\,\dd x
> =\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x - z_{+}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-\Im\int_{0}^{1/z_{+}}{\ln\pars{z_{+}x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> =-\Im\pars{\ln\pars{z_{+}}\int_{0}^{1/z_{+}}{\dd x \over 1 - x}
> +\int_{0}^{1/z_{+}}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=-\Im\pars{-\ln\pars{z_{+}}\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over z_{+}}}
> -\ln\pars{1 \over z_{+}}\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over z_{+}}}
> +\int_{0}^{1/z_{+}}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\Im\int_{0}^{1/z_{+}}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> =\Im{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over z_{+}} = \Im{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\half - \half\,\ic}
> =\color{#00f}{-{\rm G} + {1 \over 8}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}\qquad\pars{3}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm Li}_{s}\pars{z}}$ is the [Polylogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and
>   $\ds{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{z} = -\ln\pars{1 - z}}$. We used the recursive relation
>   $\ds{{\rm Li}_{s + 1}\pars{z} = \int_{0}^{z}{{\rm Li}_{s}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}$.
>   The $\ds{\color{#00f}{\mbox{last result}}}$ is found with the series representation of $\ds{{\rm Li}_{s}\pars{z}}$.

By replacing $\pars{3}$ in $\pars{2}$, we found:
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
=G + {1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you Felix for writing a proper solution. I knew after thinking about the asymmetry of $\log(1+x)$ that it would be more involved and I had no time to delve into it further.

Comment: @ChrisK It's always nice 'to move' singularities to the origin whenever it's possible. Thanks.