# Calculate $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x^6 +1)}{x^2 +1} dx $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms

I was recently doing some exercises on Integrals. I already solved the same integral but with  $x^2 + 1$ as well as $x^4 + 1$ as Argument of the logarithm. I’m struggling with this case though and WolframAlpha fails to present a step-by-step solution, can you guys help me out on this one?

Comment: Hint: if $\Im w>0$ a semicircular contour in the upper half plane gives $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(x+w)}{x^2+1}dx=\pi\ln(i+w)$ so$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(x^2+\left(2\Re w\right)x+|w|^2\right)}{x^2+1}dx=\pi\ln\left(|w|^2+1+2\Im w\right).$$Now, using sixth roots of $-1$, express $x^6+1$ as the product of three quadratics with real coefficients, including $x^2+1$, which you've solved already.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4515389/686284

Comment: Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^6)}{1+x^2}dx=  \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{2}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x}_{=\pi \ln 2}+  \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x
}_{K} $$

For integral $K$, we use the formula founded in [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4512956/732917)  stating that $$J(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+2 x \sin a+x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x =\pi\ln \left|2 \cos \frac{a}{2}\right|+|a| \ln \left|\tan \frac{a}{2}\right|-2 \operatorname{sgn} (a) \int_{0}^{\frac{|a|}{2}} \ln (\tan x) d x$$
Then $$
\begin{aligned}
K &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{2}+\sqrt{3} x+1\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(x^{2}-\sqrt{3} x+1 \right) }{1+x^{2}} dx\\
&=J\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+J\left(-\frac{\pi}{3}\right) \\
&=2 \pi \ln \left(2 \cos \frac{\pi}{6}\right) \\
&=\pi \ln 3
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\boxed{ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln \left(1+x^{6}\right)}{1+x^{2}} d x=\pi \ln 2+\pi \ln 3=\pi \ln 6 }
$$

Comment: Thank you Lai!!